# Get the count of repetition of values for a column in Qlik Sense

Tags: dashboard, qliksense

I am new to qlik sense, I have a data say - 'data', it contains four columns - 'name', 'amount', 'category', 'mode'

'name' is basically customers name, 'amount' is total spent, 'category' is like - cloths, foods, gadgets and 'mode' is offline or online.

I have created a drill down bar chart with x axis as - name/category (drill down) and y axis as amount(sum). I need to show the count of repetition in two kpi charts of mode upon selecting a particular bar

for eg - If I select the bar of foods, the kpi will show offline - 32, online -7 based on the selection I made i.e., foods

I have tried - `Count({<mode={'offline'}>}mode)`

but it's not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When using drill-down Qlik is actually selecting the values, which are "drilled". You can see that selections are made in the selection bar.

You can build the KPI objects based on the number of selected values into the drill-down fields.

[GetSelectedCount](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/August2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/FieldFunctions/getselectedcount.htm) function will return the number of **distinct** selected values in a field. The function will return 0 if nothing is selected.

An example expression:

```
= if(GetSelectedCount(category) > 0, 
    count( {<mode = {'offline'} >} category), 
    if(GetSelectedCount(name) > 0 , 
        count( {<mode = {'offline'} >} name),
        count( {<mode = {'offline'} >} SomethingElse // if nothing is selected in "name" and "category" fields
    ))
  )
```

Comment: Sir its really working, just few queries, 1) without any selection it gives 1, I just replaced SomethingElse with '', but its not working and 2) after selection it shows the number but its double the original value, suppose it shows 50 but it should be 25.

Comment: as far as i know the kpi object will display only numbers. so if the calculation returns string the kpi will display "-". if the kpi doesnt make sense when nothing is selected then you can add `KPI properties -> Add-ons -> Calculation condition` and add some "error" message to indicate to the user that selection should be made in order to calculate the object. On the topic ... it seems that your problems are data specific and unfortunately i cant help

Comment: Sir even 0 is also not working, I replaced SomethingElse with 0, I was thinking if no selection made it should display 0

Comment: possible for you to paste the actual expression?

Comment: You should be able to just change `count( {<mode = {'offline'} >} SomethingElse )` to `0` to get the behavior you want. And your values are probably doubling because of your field names having the wrong case. For example, you listed the field "mode" but it may be capitalized in your data model, like "Mode". In the expression editor, the field names should turn an orange color when they're properly spelled and capitalized.